# iframe cannot display site due to policy restriction

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

i'm trying to do simple workaround if posible beouase of policy issues.

running this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<p>Please see these following stocks</p>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/META/history/" title="META"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/MSF:GR" title="MSF:GR"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/finance/quote/AMZN:NASDAQ" title="AMZN:NASDAQ"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**getting the following error:**

Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'require-trusted-types-for'.

Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/AMZN:NASDAQ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before 'preloadResponse' settled. If you intend to use 'preloadResponse', use waitUntil() or respondWith() to wait for the promise to settle.

Refused to display 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/MSF:GR' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.bloomberg.com https://*.bloomberg.co.jp".

Refused to display 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/META/history/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.yahoo.com https://*.engadget.com https://*.pnr.ouryahoo.com https://pnr.ouryahoo.com https://*.search.aol.com https://*.onesearch.com https://*.publishing.oath.com https://*.aol.com".

any idea for workaround these issue?

Comment: This is intentional.  Those sites are telling the browser, explicitly, that they do not want to be displayed inside a frame by third-party sites.